# Connecting Firestore with Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-firestore, laravel-8

Please help,I have been trying from 2 days to connect firestore with Laravel but no success. I am unable to retrieve data.

Using https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase
the grpc extension, google cloud extension all are installed.
As per the documentation I copied the firebase config file added my parameters in .env file.

In my controller I am using

`use Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Firestore;`

Constructor looks like this:

`public function __construct(Firestore $firestore) { $this->firestore = $firestore; }`

Then I am trying to fetch data like this:

`$database = $firestore->database(); $postRef = $database->collection('categories');`

it returns empty

Following is my firestore data:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out, i was not fetching the data correctly should be like this:

`$postRef = $database->collection('categories')->document(1)->snapshot(); $postRef->data();`

For anyone who is facing the same issue.